# Find example of left Engel elements in group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given symmetric group 
$$S_3=\{e,(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,2,3),(1,3,2)\}.$$

An element $b$ in the group $G$ termed left $n$-Engel if there exist natural number $n$ such that
$$[a,_{(n)}b]=[[a,_{(n-1)},b],b]=e,$$ for all $a\in G$.

which $[a,b]=[a,_{(1)}b]=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$.

I have spent much time to check $(1,2)\in S_3$ is not left $1$-Engel element, because there exist $(2,3)\in S_3$ such that 
$$[(2,3),(1,2)]=(1,3,2).$$

Are there exist elements in $S_3$ is left-Engel? If exist, anyone can help me to find the example left Engel elements in $S_3$?

Comment: What is $a$? Do you mean "for all $a \in G$"?

Comment: Yes, I mean for all $a\in G$,

Comment: Yes $(1,2,3)$ is left Engel, because $[a,b] \in \langle (1,2,3) \rangle$ for all $a$, and so $[[a,b],b]=1$.

Comment: So, $(1,2,3)$ is 2-engel element?

Comment: Yes, I have proved $(1,2,3)$ is left Engel element. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was addressed in the comments by Derek Holt. I will answer this here so the question has an answer.

The element $b=(1,2,3)$ is a left $2$-Engel element in $S_{3}$. 
Notice that for all $a \in S_3 $ we have $[a,b] \in \langle (1,2,3) \rangle $ and so $[[a,b],b]=1$.